# Using str_replace to change text within PHP template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, str-replace

I am trying to change some text on my WooCommerce-based WP Website.

Essentially, through a filter using the str_replace I'm trying to change the text '%s reviews for %s' to be something else.

This text is included in the single-product-reviews.php file.

See below:

```
<h2><?php
if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' && ($count = $product->get_review_count() ) )
printf( _n( '%s review for %s', '%s reviews for %s', $count,   'woocommerce' ), $count, get_the_title() );
else
_e( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' );
?></h2>
```

In order to do this I'm trying to use the following, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what string I should be targetting.

```
function lnz_replace_content()
{
echo str_replace("%s reviews for %s","%s comments about %s", $product);
}
add_filter('init','lnz_replace_content');'
```

I've had a go with gettext too but that doesn't seem to work either in this case.

**OP Update**

I've had a go at using gettext, but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

As previously mentioned, I'm targeting the following code (in single-product-review.php)

```
<h2><?php
if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' && ( $count = $product->get_review_count() ) )
printf( _n( '%s review for %s', '%s reviews for %s', $count, 'woocommerce' ), $count, get_the_title() );
else
_e( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' );
?></h2>
```

If I use 'gettext' to replace 'Reviews' it works fine. If I try and get it to replace '% review for %s' it doesn't work.

Any ideas why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the template overrides to override `single-product-reviews.php` by copying it into your theme's `woocommerce` folder.

or you can filter [`gettext`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) from your theme's `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'theme_change_comment_field_names', 20, 3 );
/**
 * Change comment form default field names.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext
 */
function theme_change_comment_field_names( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

    if ( is_singular() ) {

        switch ( $translated_text ) {

            case '%s reviews for %s' :

                $translated_text = __( '%s comments for %s', 'theme_text_domain' );
                break;
           case 'Related Products' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Related Opportunities', 'theme_text_domain' );
                break;

        }

    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

Comment: Hi @helgatheviking, Pieter Goosen,

Thanks for your help. This 'gettext' filter seems to work very well in some cases but not for all.

For example, I successfully used it to change the text 'Related Products' to 'Related Opportunities'. 

The code outputting 'Related Products' was in the 'related.php' file

'code'if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?><div class="related products">
<h2><?php _e( 'Related Products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>'code'

However, for some reason, that gettext doesn't seem to be able to change the code in the single-product-review.php file.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Maybe the `is_singular()` condition? Maybe you have some other plugin conflicting? You should be able to add "Related Products" as another case in the switch statement.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with 2 ways:

1) change in language file:

```
msgid "%s reviews for %s"
msgstr "%s comments about %s"

msgid "%s review for %s"
msgstr "%s comment about %s"
```

2) chang code:

```
<h2><?php
if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' && ($count = $product->get_review_count() ) )
printf( _n( '%s review for %s', '%s reviews for %s', $count,   'woocommerce' ), $count, get_the_title() );
else
_e( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' );
?></h2>
```

to

```
<h2><?php
if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' && ($count = $product->get_review_count() ) )
printf( _n( '%s comment about %s', '%s comment about %s', $count,   'woocommerce' ), $count, get_the_title() );
else
_e( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' );
?></h2>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr Jerry. 

Which language file would I find that in please? Cheers, Linz

Comment: you can add in ``wp-content/languages`` or ``wp-content/themes/your_current_theme/languages``